# Mysql SELECT and display by high number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Some time ago i have done a query that display multiple times row that have high number. Example:

Database:

```
Name   bid

Peter  3.80
Maria  5.67
John   2.52
Robert 1.53
```

Maria show more times than others because she have value of number 5.67

It was something like `SELECT name FROM database ORDER BY bid*` .......

At call of this query I need to output names.

I want Maria to show more times because she have bid 5.7

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is quite unclear. Would you please edit your question to show more sample data, and also show the output that you would expect?

Comment: Maria show more times than Robert because she have value of number 5.67 and Robert have 1.53

Comment: Yes, this was mentionned in your original version of the question already. But it is hard to make sense out of this sentence. To help us help you, would you please provide more sample data and show us the output that you expect?

Comment: output is a single name but person with high number of bid I want to display more time at every run of query. I have done sometime ago something like `SELECT name FROM database ORDER BY bid*`....

Comment: So... the same query should return a different result when you run it several times?

Comment: exactly! Can be Maria, Maria,Peter, John, Maria, Maria more times because she have high number

Answer (score 0):

I have found guys

`SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY RAND()*bid DESC LIMIT 1;`

This is!